# Attempt to read property "photo" on bool

Tags: laravel, boolean, laravel-8

I have a problem with my laravel 8 project, everything in the `foreach` column raises an error when I test the order, but when I don't order, the error doesn't show up.

##### Controller

```php
public function index(Request $request) {
    $bookings = [];
    $studios = Studios::where('status', 1)->get();

    foreach ($this->sources as $source) {
        $models = $source['model']::where('status', '0')->get();

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $crudFieldValue = $model->getOriginal($source['date_field']);
            $crudFieldValueTo = $model->getOriginal($source['date_field_to']);
            $studios = Studios::findOrFail($model->getOriginal($source['names']));
            $user = User::findOrFail($model->getOriginal($source['field']));
            $timeBreak = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($crudFieldValueTo)->format('H:i');
    
            if (!$crudFieldValue && $crudFieldValueTo) {
                continue;
            }

            $bookings[] = [
                'title' => trim($source['prefix'] . "($studios->names)" . $user->name . " " ). " " . $timeBreak,
                'start' => $crudFieldValue,
                'end' => $crudFieldValueTo,
            ];
        }
    }

    return view('welcome', compact('studios', 'bookings'));
}
```

##### `welcome.blade.php`

```html
<div class="row">
    @foreach($studios as $studios)
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-5">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            @if($studios->photo)
                <img src="{{ $studios->photo->getUrl() }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            @endif
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Nomer studio : {{ $studios->names }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Harga : Rp{{ number_format($studios->price,2,',','.') }} / Jam</p>
                <p class="card-text"> Rp{{ number_format($studios->org,2,',','.') }} / Orang</p>
                <a href="{{ route('booking', ['studio' => $studios->names])  }}" class="btn btn-primary">Booking</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: <img src="{{ $studios->photo->getUrl() ?? '' }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">   can you try this

Comment: _everything in the foreach column raises an error_ : Please share the raised error.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate the array item name from the array name

```
@foreach($studios as $studio)
@if($studio->photo)
   <img src="{{ $studio->photo->getUrl() }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller file, I think
`$studios = Studios::where('status',1)->get();` in this line $studios var getting a false value somehow, that's why in your blade file you are getting an error that you want to read property called photo on that var but its already in the false state, it neither any object to read.